# Easy Effects 7.0.5 is preventing media from streaming

Tags: sound, streaming, media, pipewire, equalizer

I've been using Easy Effects for some time with no issues, using Ziyad Nazem's presets. I'm using Ubuntu 23.04 with GNOME 44.2

When I start easy effects, any media such as youtube, spotify, netflix, etc., stops streaming. This is the same with any browser. I created another user, and the problem persists there. When I click "disable" in Easy Effects on whichever output (i.e., firefox, chrome, etc), the streaming starts up again. Otherwise, I get the swirly loading sign (using youtube as an example), and I can skip around the video, but it won't stream. Spotify won't play anything.

Does anyone know what's going on?